# realtime output of Python subprocess to jupyter and in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, subprocess

As the title say: I need a realtime output of a Python subprocess to Jupyter and in a file.

I'm running a python file which is called from a Jupyter notebook. In this file, there is a subprocess to call TensorFlow and start the training of a model (so this is a really long process).

It's really practical for me to actually see the logs in Jupyter and also have them saved to a file as the model is training.

There are quite a few similar questions already on Stack Overflow, but none cover exactly my question and I pretty much tried all the solution I found out there.

With everything I experienced from those other questions. It's either I can save it to a file real time or display in Jupyter real time, but I haven't found a way to do both real time.

The closest is to use the stdout=PIPE; it will print real time in Jupyter and once the process is finished it will save the beginning of the logs into the file (for some reason it's truncated). But it won't save the log in real time, nor all the logs.

Here are a part of all the various things I tried: (each scenario is separated by 2 jump lines)

```
#with Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
#    for line in p.stdout:
#        #print(line, end='') # process line here
#        with open(trainingLogFile, "a") as file:
#            file.write(output)
#if p.returncode != 0:
#    raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)


#this work but only in the file
#log = open(trainingLogFile, 'a')
#log.flush() 
#with subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=log, stderr=log, universal_newlines=True) as proc:
#    while proc.poll() is None:
#        print('TEST')
#        print(proc.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8"))
#        log.flush()
#        time.sleep(0.05)
#log.close()


#with subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as proc:
#    while proc.poll() is None:
#        output = proc.stdout.readline()
#        if output != b'':
#            #print(output.rstrip())
#            with open(trainingLogFile, "a") as file:
#                file.write(output)
#        time.sleep(0.05)
#stop process
#proc.terminate()


#proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=0)
#while proc.poll() is None:
#    output = proc.stdout.readline()
#    if output != b'':
#        #print(output.rstrip())
#        with open(trainingLogFile, "a") as file:
#            file.write(output)
#    time.sleep(0.05)
#stop process
#proc.terminate()


#proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
#for stdout_line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ""):
#    print('TEST')
#    print(stdout_line)
#    with open(trainingLogFile, "a") as file:
#        file.write(stdout_line)
#proc.stdout.close()
#proc.wait()


# invoke process
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
# Poll process.stdout to show stdout live
while True:
    output = proc.stdout.readline()
    if proc.poll() is not None:
        break
    if output:
        print(output.strip())
        with open(trainingLogFile, "a") as file:
            file.write(stdout_line)
    rc = proc.poll()


#log = open(trainingLogFile, 'a')
#log.flush() 
#with subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=log, stderr=log, universal_newlines=True) as proc:
#    while True:
#        output = proc.stdout.readline()
#        if proc.poll() is not None:
#            break
#        if output:
#            print(output.strip())
#        rc = proc.poll()
#log.close()
```